# Rails and max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is ruby code:

> file = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select LOAD_FILE('#{full_file_path}')").fetch_row()[0]

The file is 180M and my `max_allowed_packet` in my.cnf was set to 100M, so I changed it to 500M with:

```
set global max_allowed_packet=524288000;
```

The value is changed:

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 524288000 |
+--------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I still got error.

> From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet
>
> When you change the message buffer size by changing the value of the max_allowed_packet variable, **you should also change the buffer size on the client side if your client program permits it.** **The default max_allowed_packet value built in to the client library is 1GB, but individual client programs might override this.** For example, mysql and mysqldump have defaults of 16MB and 24MB, respectively. They also enable you to change the client-side value by setting max_allowed_packet on the command line or in an option file.

So maybe ruby mysql client have some small value, and changing on server side is not enough?

Comment: I restarted httpd server and it works now. How to close this question?

Comment: Be super extra careful when injecting things like `full_file_path` in your SQL. What error do you get, specifically?